# Is there a way to automatically develop matrices in Ovtave from txt.files or Excel.files?

Tags: excel, octave, txt

I wanted to ask if there is a way to develop matrices from txt.files or excel.files in Octave?

There is a lot of data and the matrices would all be unequal in size.

I would like to have a solution for how Octave independently develops the matrices from this data.
The first 3 epochs of my txt.files are as follows (Excel.files are equal):

```
>  216  0 200021.0  0  27                   Nord    Ost Höhe        Uhr         Ele Gewichtungsmatrix P         l-vektor
G02 90.1307 39.7929 -0.6509 47.835      G02 0.28008766  -0.4136 0.8663  1   0   0       39.7929     0.657028746     -0.6509
G06 51.6868 27.4026 0.0942  41.988      G06 -0.095831837    -0.6363 0.7654  1   0   0       27.4026     0.756297479     0.0942
G12 76.2555 64.5358 -0.6129 49.52       G12 -0.08688968 -0.1004 0.9911  1   0   0       64.5358     1       -0.6129
G24 152.691 23.2248 -0.5601 40.024      G24 0.105235503 -0.3136 -0.9437 1   0   0       23.2248     0.044889963     -0.5601
G25 290.2004    72.0358 -0.594  50.79       G25 -0.377192249    -0.8999 0.2190  1   0   0       72.0358     1       -0.594
G29 212.6439    34.8495 0.299   42.095      G29 -0.529941856    0.7977  -0.2878 1   0   0       34.8495     0.758555093     0.299
G31 310.7814    16.6268 -0.5245 42.489      G31 0.589888171 -0.1420 -0.7949 1   0   0       16.6268     0.323065011     -0.5245
G32 260.8512    30.0106 -0.2712 47.503      G32 -0.163909034    -0.0163 -0.9863 1   0   0       30.0106     -0.3968609      -0.2712
E01 287.5385    43.4299 -0.8272 45.812      E01 0.070380984 -0.8484 -0.5247 0   1   0       43.4299     -0.875021299        -0.8272
E04 282.3375    24.3524 1.1112  44.814      E04 0.652946618 -0.2806 -0.7035 0   1   0       24.3524     -0.798771228        1.1112
E09 333.5493    10.4841 -0.6396 39.889      E09 -0.419696483    -0.2519 -0.8720 0   1   0       10.4841     0.201267578     -0.6396
E13 120.8855    46.3654 0.0933  47.462      E13 -0.047740587    -0.7243 0.6878  0   1   0       46.3654     0.807951002     0.0933
E15 51.1299 32.709  0.2468  44.429      E15 0.177956886 0.2086  0.9617  0   1   0       32.7090     0.008964638     0.2468
E21 67.3987 81.0692 -0.1922 49.053      E21 -0.118688728    -0.8097 -0.5747 0   1   0       81.0692     1       -0.1922
E27 99.0763 27.8029 0.7416  43.344      E27 -0.10323116 0.8849  0.4542  0   1   0       27.8029     0.891343699     0.7416
C08 55.3237 31.7253 0.0905  39.688      C08 0.322883236 -0.8961 0.3045  0   0   1       31.7253     -0.749804668        0.0905
C13 81.4813 33.6655 0.5316  42.764      C13 -0.615313057    0.1248  0.7783  0   0   1       33.6655     0.746000511     0.5316
C24 300.3156    21.5825 -0.1124 43.979      C24 -0.265484009    0.8784  0.3974  0   0   1       21.5825     0.899985397     -0.1124
C26 287.2586    70.4128 1.098   52.028      C26 -0.052812888    -0.2644 0.9630  0   0   1       70.4128     1       1.098
C29 71.5378 54.0883 -0.2743 49.849      C29 0.584602504 -0.5115 -0.6297 0   0   1       54.0883     0.513381134     -0.2743
C35 174.4506    53.055  0.6689  40.858      C35 -0.086429029    0.9347  0.3448  0   0   1       53.0550     0.904735186     0.6689
>  216  0 200022.0  0  27                   Nord    Ost Höhe        Uhr         Ele Gewichtungsmatrix P         l-vektor
G02 90.1213 39.7948 -0.7275 47.626      G02 0.277097635 -0.4175 0.8654  1   0   0       39.7948     0.658214519     -0.7275
G06 51.6795 27.4001 -0.0076 42.191      G06 -0.100175311    -0.6337 0.7671  1   0   0       27.4001     0.75504519      -0.0076
G12 76.2634 64.5286 -0.5364 49.5        G12 -0.081463926    -0.0956 0.9921  1   0   0       64.5286     1       -0.5364
G24 152.6925    23.2176 -0.4773 40.04       G24 0.107874284 -0.3199 -0.9413 1   0   0       23.2176     0.051408388     -0.4773
G25 290.2106    72.0432 -0.5178 50.773      G25 -0.368595466    -0.9051 0.2118  1   0   0       72.0432     1       -0.5178
G29 212.6465    34.8573 0.1952  42.152      G29 -0.530750594    0.7944  -0.2953 1   0   0       34.8573     0.754659053     0.1952
G31 310.7813    16.6335 -0.5057 42.347      G31 0.584683049 -0.1408 -0.7989 1   0   0       16.6335     0.317382203     -0.5057
G32 260.8436    30.0066 -0.293  47.481      G32 -0.160097847    -0.0147 -0.9870 1   0   0       30.0066     -0.393597161        -0.293
E01 287.5421    43.4352 -0.847  45.898      E01 0.073673474 -0.8509 -0.5202 0   1   0       43.4352     -0.876266506        -0.847
E04 282.3316    24.3499 1.1323  44.793      E04 0.649666072 -0.2837 -0.7053 0   1   0       24.3499     -0.797696582        1.1323
E09 333.5448    10.4864 -0.6383 40.093      E09 -0.41910005 -0.2489 -0.8731 0   1   0       10.4864     0.199233858     -0.6383
E13 120.8787    46.3703 0.0863  47.651      E13 -0.052908609    -0.7273 0.6843  0   1   0       46.3703     0.809956689     0.0863
E15 51.1242 32.7061 0.1667  44.78       E15 0.180964321 0.2097  0.9609  0   1   0       32.7061     0.006335539     0.1667
E21 67.4271 81.0649 -0.1842 49.266      E21 -0.095357984    -0.8103 -0.5782 0   1   0       81.0649     1       -0.1842
E27 99.0807 27.7979 0.6597  43.467      E27 -0.106849402    0.8822  0.4586  0   1   0       27.7979     0.89050396      0.6597
C08 55.3206 31.7264 -0.0861 39.91       C08 0.319990943 -0.8968 0.3055  0   0   1       31.7264     -0.749243592        -0.0861
C13 81.4788 33.6683 0.6752  42.836      C13 -0.617131497    0.1268  0.7766  0   0   1       33.6683     0.74744017      0.6752
C24 300.3171    21.5885 -0.0682 44.104      C24 -0.267489719    0.8803  0.3919  0   0   1       21.5885     0.900625997     -0.0682
C26 287.2502    70.419  1.1204  52.078      C26 -0.053812734    -0.2581 0.9646  0   0   1       70.4190     1       1.1204
C29 71.5283 54.0843 -0.2705 49.812      C29 0.581591916 -0.5187 -0.6266 0   0   1       54.0843     0.516366056     -0.2705
C35 174.4479    53.0624 0.6352  40.934      C35 -0.084130911    0.9374  0.3379  0   0   1       53.0624     0.905142599     0.6352
>  216  0 200023.0  0  27                   Nord    Ost Höhe        Uhr         Ele Gewichtungsmatrix P         l-vektor
G02 90.1119 39.7968 -0.7359 47.749      G02 0.274103488 -0.4216 0.8644  1   0   0       39.7968     0.659460135     -0.7359
G06 51.6721 27.3976 -0.0462 42.155      G06 -0.104548274    -0.6311 0.7687  1   0   0       27.3976     0.753788182     -0.0462
G12 76.2712 64.5214 -0.5706 49.554      G12 -0.07612385 -0.0908 0.9930  1   0   0       64.5214     1       -0.5706
G24 152.694 23.2103 -0.5263 40.012      G24 0.110556629 -0.3262 -0.9388 1   0   0       23.2103     0.058014625     -0.5263
G25 290.2207    72.0505 -0.5534 50.779      G25 -0.359994038    -0.9102 0.2047  1   0   0       72.0505     1       -0.5534
G29 212.6492    34.8651 0.1105  42.277      G29 -0.5315926  0.7910  -0.3028 1   0   0       34.8651     0.7507171       0.1105
G31 310.7812    16.6402 -0.6557 42.347      G31 0.579451926 -0.1396 -0.8030 1   0   0       16.6402     0.311685148     -0.6557
G32 260.836 30.0027 -0.2345 47.42       G32 -0.156367788    -0.0131 -0.9876 1   0   0       30.0027     -0.390408953        -0.2345
E01 287.5456    43.4406 -0.8    45.908      E01 0.076902012 -0.8534 -0.5156 0   1   0       43.4406     -0.877509892        -0.8
E04 282.3257    24.3474 1.1593  44.977      E04 0.646367177 -0.2868 -0.7071 0   1   0       24.3474     -0.79661695     1.1593
E09 333.5403    10.4887 -0.8681 39.973      E09 -0.418483684    -0.2460 -0.8743 0   1   0       10.4887     0.197199083     -0.8681
E13 120.872 46.3752 0.091   47.823      E13 -0.058045365    -0.7303 0.6807  0   1   0       46.3752     0.81194293      0.091
E15 51.1185 32.7032 0.2665  44.668      E15 0.183988402 0.2107  0.9601  0   1   0       32.7032     0.003706388     0.2665
E21 67.4556 81.0606 -0.1483 49.091      E21 -0.072007781    -0.8102 -0.5817 0   1   0       81.0606     1       -0.1483
E27 99.0851 27.7929 0.4906  43.261      E27 -0.110442872    0.8794  0.4631  0   1   0       27.7929     0.889641958     0.4906
C08 55.3175 31.7275 -0.4123 39.874      C08 0.31709715  -0.8975 0.3066  0   0   1       31.7275     -0.74868161     -0.4123
C13 81.4762 33.6711 0.5131  42.77       C13 -0.618926175    0.1288  0.7748  0   0   1       33.6711     0.748873968     0.5131
C24 300.3187    21.5945 0.1085  44.081      C24 -0.269580156    0.8821  0.3863  0   0   1       21.5945     0.901234173     0.1085
C26 287.2416    70.4252 1.2233  52.067      C26 -0.054758719    -0.2518 0.9662  0   0   1       70.4252     1       1.2233
C29 71.5189 54.0804 -0.2273 49.77       C29 0.578494282 -0.5258 -0.6236 0   0   1       54.0804     0.519268401     -0.2273
C35 174.4452    53.0698 0.693   40.744      C35 -0.081814125    0.9401  0.3309  0   0   1       53.0698     0.905500446     0.693
```

Every new epoch starts with this ">".

Thanks for your suggestions!

Greetings

Comment: I think the best thing is to write a for loop that reads every line and you can handle the especial cases as appropriate for you.

Comment: If you always have the same row-layout within your matrix, apart from the "header", do as @AnderBiguri suggests. Write a loop to start a new matrix for collection at every `>` at the start of a line, then attach all lines until the next `>`. Check the docs on `fgetl()`

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the quick respons.
My Problem is, that there are many epochs in this RINEX file. They have from 26 to 29 lines. Does it work anyway with a fgetl()-loop?

Comment: Or how can such a loop look like? Im kinda new to Octave and I still have many difficulties with it.